# Diagnosing a failed motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motor-controller

How would you determine if a DC motor has failed?

I have a ~9 year old treadmill that suddenly stopped working. As far as I can tell, superficially, all the electronics are good. Nothing's obviously scorched or melted or burning. The motor simply stopped turning the tread, and the control console isn't reporting any problems.

This treadmill is fairly easy to service, and I'm able to remove the cover over the motor, exposing the motor and motor controller board. The motor has a label saying it's 1.5 HP continuous duty rated for 90VDC and 12A.

I disconnected it from the motor controller and attached a multi-meter to the controllers motor outputs, powered on the treadmill, activated the motor, and measured 154V.

I don't have a power supply that can provide 90V, but I was able to hookup the motor to a 30V power supply, but the motor didn't activate. Most DC motors still turn with a lower voltage, but maybe there's just too much load to move at such a relatively low voltage.

How do I determine whether the motor, the motor controller, or both, have failed?

Is the fact that the motor controller is outputting 154V, more than the motor's rated 90V, a possible sign that the controller has failed? Or could that just be an initial high startup voltage to compensate for static friction on the tread?

I've looked up the price of replacement parts, and both the motor and controller cost around $230. Even if I have to replace both, that's cheaper than buying a new treadmill. How do I determine which has failed and should be replaced?

Edit: I figured out how to open up the motor, revealing what I think are the brushes.

[image: motor brushes]

As you can see, the brushes are in the form of two spring-loaded metal bars that protrude towards the axle. One of the brushes looks to be worn all the way down, probably to the point where it's no longer touching the rotor. Is this what's causing the motor to fail?

How would I find a replacement brush? It's attached via a couple rivets, but I could easy drill those out and attach a new part with a small bolt and nut, but I have no idea how to identity this brush, much less find a vendor.

Comment: Have you inspected the motor's brushes? Can you disconnect the motor's shaft from the load? Can you turn the motor shaft by hand? What happens to the 30V supply voltage when you attach the motor?

Comment: @CharlesCowie After disconnecting the motor from the load, I can freely turn the shaft. If I attach my 30V supply to the disconnected motor, it runs sporadically. I see small flashes of light coming from inside the motor. It runs for a few seconds, then it stops. If I manually turn the flywheel, that sometimes starts it again, and the power supply indicates it's consuming current. I can't disassemble the motor, so I'm unable to inspect the brushes.

Comment: There should be a couple of brush-holder caps that can be unscrewed or some other access to the brushes. Replacing the brushes is probably the only motor repair that is reasonably possible. The motor has probably failed. Can you try the motor controller with the motor disconnected from the load?  If you turn the speed setting down, is the controller output voltage less?

Comment: @CharlesCowie When I change the speed via the console, the voltage remains a constant 154V. However, there appears to be a magnetic sensor positioned next to the flywheel, presumably to measure rpms, so it might not be varying voltage because it's not seeing a commensurate change in rotation.

Comment: The output voltage is likely pulse width modulated and the multimeter may be reading the peak. If there is voltage when the motor is not responding at all, the controller may limiting the average voltage to a low value. If the 30 V power supply is electronic, it may be limiting the current. I would be tempted to try a car battery, but I would hesitate to do that without a starter solenoid relay.

Comment: Hit it with a hammer in the axe of the brushes. Sometimes the brushes will contact again. This is only to check, that your electronic is still operating.

Comment: Brushes usually made from graphite and worn by time.  They are expendable and replaceable. Clean collector too, sparks between brushes and collector make it dirty.

Comment: @CharlesCowie You were right. There were small panels I could remove to "unplug" the brushes. Unfortunately, I ended up disassembling the motor and drilling out the rivets to the brush housing before I realized this. And indeed, one of the brushes appears almost worn down to the housing. Any idea where I could find a replacement? There's no part number, and I can't find the exact dimensions on any websites I see selling brush replacements.

Comment: I would look on eBay. There are a lot of small business people that sell things like that. They are not always very good about describing things, but they might be cheap enough to risk getting something useless. McMaster-Carr has brushes, but they may have a minimum order requirement or high shipping & handling  charge.  Grainger has brushes, but they seem to be for motors that have brush kit part number information.